# SQL Server UPDATE Column if Same CODE and DeptID Don't Exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, parameters

When I execute a Procedure I would like to UPDATE table1 and SET the new values for the CODE, NUMBER, and ADDRESS columns only if the same CODE and DeptID do not exist. If I change the CODE to an existing name in table1 it is OK as long as the DeptID is different.

Example:
[image: table1]

Say I want to change Beta to Delta. That is fine because they have different DeptIDs. So I want to UPDATE everything, aka the third row in my example would now have the values (1, Delta, 'whateverNUMBER', 'whateverADDRESS')

But if I wanted to take that same third row Beta and change the CODE to Alpha I don't want to allow that and I don't want to SET the NUMBER or ADDRESS either because there is already a row with CODE Alpha and DeptID 1.

How would I be able to accomplish this?

Here is one of my attempts which does not work:

```
UPDATE dbo.table1
SET 
   CODE = @CODE
   ,NUMBER = @NUMBER
   ,ADDRESS = @ADDRESS
WHERE ID = @ID
AND NOT EXISTS
    (
     SELECT NAME FROM dbo.table1
     WHERE NAME = @NAME
     AND ID = @ID
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work if you have the commas in the right place for syntax and specify the old code:

```
UPDATE dbo.table1
    SET CODE = @CODE,
        NUMBER = @NUMBER,
        ADDRESS = @ADDRESS
     WHERE ID = @ID AND
           CODE = @OLDCODE AND
           NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                       FROM dbo.table1
                       WHERE NAME = @NAME AND ID = @ID
                      );
```

Comment: Thank you I did have the commas I just forgot to put them in. It works fine as long as I change the CODE as well, but if I just want to change everything else then it doesn't work. So maybe including the oldcode will work but I am unsure what to specify as oldcode, could you clarify please.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be to add a unique constraint for columns DeptId and Code.
This will prevent any duplicate insert as well as an update to already existing values.

The constraint will even prevent any changes performed directly against the table and not just within your update statement.